# App Should exit on Smart Hub in Samsung smart TV

Tags: jquery, html, samsung-smart-tv

This is an unanswered issue on samsungdforum, and I have not found a satisfactory answer here so far..

My app has been rejected by Samsung guys because the app does not exit on smart hub. When a user presses the smarthub button, smarthub does come up, but the app is still running in the background. The proof of this is that when we relaunch the app, it starts from where it was left.

As far as I know, this code will take the app to smart hub:

```
    var widgetAPI = new Common.API.Widget();
  widgetAPI.sendReturnEvent();
  mwPlugin.SetSource(0);
```

The above code is behaving fine for a blu-ray player but for tv, it is only minimizing the app, and if there is a video running in the app, then this code will mess with the video on the tv.

And this code will exit the app on broadcasting screen:

```
 var widgetAPI = new Common.API.Widget(); 
    widgetAPI.sendExitEvent();
 mwPlugin.SetSource(0);
```

So can any one suggest how to exit the app on smart hub in Samsung smart TV?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get your hands on an Application instance, it has an exit() method.

```
var app = tizen.application.getCurrentApplication();
app.exit();
```

As described in [documentation](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/api-references/tizen-web-device-api-references/application-api/). Also the [Guide](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/fundamentals/terminating-applications) has a section on how to terminate applicatons.

Comment: That time tizen platform was not there

Comment: Yup, realized it is pretty old. Have you solved it eventually?